# Is it allowed in this community to link to definitions proposed in other SE sites instead of copy-pasting them?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

Is it allowed in this community to link to definitions proposed in other SE sites instead of copy-pasting them?

Specifically, I try to discuss about organization types in software industry and suppose there are more general economics terms not even specific to this industry, but is it okay to place here just a link to that question?

https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/1387/which-organization-types-are-targeted-by-devops-transformation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It isn't contrary to any guidance I have seen.  But I suggest the question you should be asking yourself is what is convenient for those reading a post.  Not providing a standard definition of an economic term, which many readers would be familiar with, but giving instead a link to the definition to help any who are not, is fine.  But if you are *proposing* a definition, it would be more helpful to include it in your post, rather than just adding a link.